# Inserting object into embedded document

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to learn the mongoDB driver for C#. First time using the driver on a NoSQL database. I'm trying to insert an object inside a collection inside another object but cant get it to work. I have been searching for examples with no luck.

**Current Code :**

```
    public class PlayList
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Owner")]
        public Guid Owner { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("UrlList")]
        public List<Url> UrlList { get; set; }

        //Curret URL  info. 
        [BsonElement("CurrentUrl")]
        public string CurrentUrl { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("version")]
        public Guid version { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("time")]
        public string time { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("isRepeat")]
        public bool isRepeat { get; set; }
    }
}


 public class Url
    {
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Url")]
        public string UrlPart { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

**Driver code**
Below wont compile but it's what I want to do.

```
public void AddUrlToList(Url url, Guid playListId)
{
    MongoCollection<PlayList> collection = GetPlayListForEdit();
    try
    {
        //No idea how to insert the url object into the playlist collection of urls. 
        var q1 = Query<PlayList>.EQ(e => e.Id, playListId);
        var editList = collection.Find(query);
        var q2 = Query<PlayList>.EQ(e => e.UrlList); // not sure how to query inner collection
        editList. /// select inner collection
                  /// Insert the Url Object into it .. . //collection.Insert(url);
                  /// Done .
    }

    catch (MongoCommandException ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = Query<PlayList>.EQ(e => e.Id, playListId);
var update = Update<PlayList>.Push(e => e.UrlList, url);

collection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Do you mabey have some good resource where there are some examples of basic syntax using the mongo driver?  :)

Comment: basically Im using the mongo driver docs, for start  use these: https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M101N/about?_ga=1.50527721.1933981110.1415129643, http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524602/Beginners-guide-to-using-MongoDB-and-the-offic